# Errors in DLookup as a control source in access form

Tags: ms-access, textbox

I have a text box with the control source of *Dlookup* function. But the *Dlookup* format makes me crazy, I tried a hundred times to refer another combo box value as criteria in *Dlookup* function. I got either "# name?" or "# Error".

I tried this:

```
=DLookUp("[Contact]","Supllier","[Company]='" & [Forms]![PurchaseOrder]![cboSupplierCompany] & "'")
```

and got `"# Error"`

when I input :

```
=DLookUp("[Contact]","Supllier","[Company]='" & [Me]![cboSupplierCompany] & "'")
```

I got `"# Name?"`

Comment: Wrapping code snippets in a code block (the { } symbol in the edit bar when you ask/edit a question) will make your code much easier to read.  It preserves spacing, tabs, new lines and even highlights certain keywords. A tidy, well-written question is more likely to get more positive attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. The right way to use Dlookup in a expression is to use the expression editor to select table field and form control.

the working expression of Dlookup in my textbox is :

`DLookUp(" [Supplier]![Contact] ","Supplier","  [Supplier]![Company] ='" & [cboSupplierCompany] & "'")`

Answer (score 0):

Using a SQL-query window above-like versions work fine.

But they did not work in the `ControlSource` property setting. Here you have to use semicolons (`;`) instead of commas (`,`). At least in a German language settings environment. The control setting in German is:

```
Steuerelementinhalt
= DLookUp(" [Supplier]![Contact] ";"Supplier";"  [Supplier]![Company] ='" & [cboSupplierCompany] & "'"
```